# Where can I ask questions about Stack Exchange's data explorer?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, data-explorer

I have been unable to find an *ask question* button on https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

So where can I ask a question about *data.stackexchange*? (Actually, I have a question about my SQL query which I am trying to compose on *data.stackexchange*.)

Meta provided a question in the FAQ about what kind of questions a user should ask here. But where can I find the list/description with the question kind and is there an appropriate site to ask on (within the scope of Stack Overflow and its related sites)?

I have not asked my actual question directly about an SQL query, because I am not sure if this is the appropriate platform to inquire about that thing.

Comment: You can ask them right here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Meta Stack Exchange is the right site to ask such questions, it's the meta site for all things Stack Exchange, including the data explorer.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Now I should post my actual question as new Rather than editing this one. Right Sir Martijn Pieters?

Comment: Yeah, better make that a new question, since editing this one would make my answer (and any others that could follow) invalid.

Comment: hahaha. Exactly that's the point. Thanks